# How do I check which JNLP file that has been selected to run?

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

I deploy an app through Java Web Start. What I want to know is can it be possible to locate the JNLP file that the application was launched from ?

I want to try and use specific configurations for different environments, and although they may use the same application, I want to distinguish specific settings for what JNLP file has been used.

I've looked online for a while now with no luck, and I'm beginning to think if it is even possible.

If anyone has had this issue or has any tutorials/similar discussions, please comment with the link.

Comment: You can pass configuration from each JNLP as system properties and/or command line arguments.

Comment: Does this mean your checking against system properties for each version though ? Because if further down the line numerous JNLP exists, would it not mean consistent updates to the code ? I've found a solution here : https://community.oracle.com/thread/2294999?tstart=0 which I'm going to try and replicate

Comment: As a commenter on that page points out:  “You should not be relying on use of internal classes. This can break any minute.”  Whether checking a system property requires changing your code more than once depends on what you're doing.  Which settings do you need from the JNLPs?

Comment: Its not necessarily the settings themselves, I'm going to deduce from the JNLP file what settings to use based on naming conventions depicted from the name of the JNLP file. So each JNLP file will represent a different configuration file which is read and then used by the application.

Comment: Why not use explicit system properties?  That's essentially what they're for.  And they will make the intent much clearer.

Comment: Hmm good idea, if you want to put that as an answer I can accept it because that should sort the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I check which JNLP file that has been selected to run ?

Put a unique `property` in the `resources` section of each JNLP file.

```xml
<property name="jnlp.id" value="some-value"/>
```